# PDF of the product of two independent uniformly distributed random variables

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables, uniform-distribution

Suppose that X and Y are independent U[0,1]-random variables. Find the probability density function of the product V = XY.

I have seen that ()=(−1)^(−1)*log(−1)*()/(−1)! for the product of n independent random variables from 0 < z < 1 but I am not sure how to derive this.

Answer (score 1):

$P(XY\leq t)=EP(XY \leq t |Y)=E(\frac t Y I_{Y >t}+I_{Y \leq t})$ so $P(XY\leq t)=t\log (\frac 1 t)+t$ for $0<t<1$. The density is $\log (\frac 1 t)$ for $0<t<1$.

Comment: Where did you get the -tlogt +t after the indicator functions?

Comment: @gigglegirl6 $\int_t^{1} \frac t y \, dy=t\log\, y|_t^{1}=-t\log\, t$